# Maintain mysql configuration with puppet

Tags: puppet

I recently add the mysql module from puppetLabs in version 7.0 on our RHEL Satellite for managing all our MySql's servers and hold them with  idempotency configuration and bloc any unwanted configuration.

In this case, a user with Granted privileges is able to create a Database (like root@localhost) and so add manually a Database with the command create database dbname; for example.

Problem, If i run my pupppet agent -t on my lab server, puppet is just ensuring that databeses defined in my smart class "Databeses" exist (or not) and do nothing...

The result expected was it can remove any modification (like database creation) when ran the agent.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

Since `Mysql_database` is an "ensurable" plugin type that implements prefetching, you should be able to use [the `Resources` resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.1/types/resources.html) to purge any unmanaged databases that are created on managed nodes.  It might look something like this:

```
resources { 'mysql_database': purge => true }
```

**Do this only if you're *certain* that you really want it!**

Additionally, you might want to try some runs in `--noop` mode to look for issues before going live.  That could help you recognize unanticipated issues, such as databases you want to keep -- belonging to MySQL itself, for example -- but are not currently managing.